# Javascript console error elem.find() is not a function

Tags: javascript

I am working on learning to make jQuery plugins and made the following plugin, forgive me for the wall of code:

```
$.fn.addressForm = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var elem = $(this);

            $.each(elem.find(".addr-country select"), function ( elem ) {

                $(this).on('change', function (elem ) {
                    // var elem = $(this).parents(".form-address");
                    if ($(this).val() === "US") {
                        elem.find(".addr-state label").html("State"); // eror gets thrown about this line
                        elem.find(".addr-postal-code label").html("Zip");

                        elem.find(".addr-street-1").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-street-2").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-city").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-state").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-postal-code").show();

                        var states = [
                            { text: "AL", value: "AL" },
                            { text: "AK", value: "AK" },
                            { text: "AZ", value: "AZ" },
                            { text: "AR", value: "AR" },
                            { text: "CA", value: "CA" },
                            { text: "CO", value: "CO" },
                            { text: "CT", value: "CT" },
                            { text: "DE", value: "DE" },
                            { text: "FL", value: "FL" },
                            { text: "GA", value: "GA" },
                            { text: "HI", value: "HI" },
                            { text: "ID", value: "ID" },
                            { text: "IL", value: "IL" },
                            { text: "IN", value: "IN" },
                            { text: "IA", value: "IA" },
                            { text: "KS", value: "KS" },
                            { text: "KY", value: "KY" },
                            { text: "LA", value: "LA" },
                            { text: "ME", value: "ME" },
                            { text: "MD", value: "MD" },
                            { text: "MA", value: "MA" },
                            { text: "MI", value: "MI" },
                            { text: "MN", value: "MN" },
                            { text: "MS", value: "MS" },
                            { text: "MO", value: "MO" },
                            { text: "MT", value: "MT" },
                            { text: "NE", value: "NE" },
                            { text: "NV", value: "NV" },
                            { text: "NH", value: "NH" },
                            { text: "NJ", value: "NJ" },
                            { text: "NM", value: "NM" },
                            { text: "NY", value: "NY" },
                            { text: "NC", value: "NC" },
                            { text: "ND", value: "ND" },
                            { text: "OH", value: "OH" },
                            { text: "OK", value: "OK" },
                            { text: "OR", value: "OR" },
                            { text: "PA", value: "PA" },
                            { text: "RI", value: "RI" },
                            { text: "SC", value: "SC" },
                            { text: "SD", value: "SD" },
                            { text: "TN", value: "TN" },
                            { text: "TX", value: "TX" },
                            { text: "UT", value: "UT" },
                            { text: "VT", value: "CT" },
                            { text: "VA", value: "VA" },
                            { text: "WA", value: "WA" },
                            { text: "WV", value: "WV" },
                            { text: "WI", value: "WI" },
                            { text: "WY", value: "WY" },
                            { text: "D.C.", value: "D.C." }
                        ];

                        elem.find(".addr-state select").empty();

                        $.each(states, function (index, value) {
                            var o = new Option(value.text, value.value);
                            $(o).html(value.text);
                            elem.find(".addr-state select").append(o);
                        });
                    }

                    if ($(this).val() === "CA") {
                        // Update labels
                        elem.find(".addr-state label").html("Province");
                        elem.find(".addr-postal-code label").html("Postal Code");

                        // Show fields
                        elem.find(".addr-street-1").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-street-2").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-city").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-state").show();
                        elem.find(".addr-postal-code").show();

                        var states = [
                            { text: "AB", value: "AB" },
                            { text: "BC", value: "BC" },
                            { text: "MB", value: "MB" },
                            { text: "NB", value: "NB" },
                            { text: "NL", value: "NL" },
                            { text: "NS", value: "NS" },
                            { text: "ON", value: "ON" },
                            { text: "PE", value: "PE" },
                            { text: "QC", value: "QC" },
                            { text: "SK", value: "SK" },
                            { text: "NT", value: "NT" },
                            { text: "NU", value: "NU" },
                            { text: "YT", value: "YT" }
                        ];

                        // Reset state options
                        elem.find(".addr-state select").empty();
                        $.each(states, function (index, value) {
                            var o = new Option(value.text, value.value);
                            $(o).html(value.text);
                            elem.find(".addr-state select").append(o);
                        });
                    }
                })
            });
        })
    }
```

For some reason passing in elem to the on change function is not getting recognized. If I were to un-comment the line that says `var elem = $(this).parents(".form-address");` it works fine. But I need the $(this) instance of the original selected element to be used, not a specific class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `elem` that `find` is called on (within `$(this).on('change', ...)`) is a DOM event. It takes precedence over the one you defined in the outer scope.

Comment: `elem` is a parameter in your event listener and in your `.each()`. It shouldn’t be in either of those (event listeners aren’t even passed an element). Avoiding shadowing names is also generally a good idea.

Comment: So how can i reference the instance element from this.each inside .on('change',... ?